# Can not create sub-interface in Cisco CGR 1240

Tags: cisco, router, interface

I follow a tutorial, there shows the method of create sub-interface:

[image]

but in my actual situation, I can not do this:

```
Router(config)#interface gigabitEthernet 2/1.100
                                           ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

my router is CGR 1240 in Cisco Packet Tracer.

Answer (score 0):

The CGR 1240 does not appear to support 802.1q VLAN's, based on the Cisco Data Sheet for the router:

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/routers/1000-series-connected-grid-routers/datasheet_c78-696278.html